# Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.impute'

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, imputation

I'm importing the `sklean.impute.SimpleImputer` using

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
```

But got an error

> error: No module named 'sklearn.impute'.

Installed sklearn 0.19.1 using command `!pip install sklearn`. How to see if it's the development version? Also, where can I access the logs?

Comment: Have you installed `sklearn`? If yes, please add more information on how you installed `sklearn` and how you are running `jupyter-notebook`. attaching logs will help you in getting an answer quickly.

Comment: SimpleImputer is available in development version of scikit. Which version you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The pip version of scikit-learn is now 0.20+.

The impute submodule is part of scikit-learn version 0.20. It is not on pypi yet, so if you have to use that function, install the dev version of scikit-learn by `pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`